# What does this failure point to?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am using Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview edition. When I create a blank project UWP project and drop a few controls on the DESIGN pane, I see a lot of squiggly blue lines and this message,"XSurfUwp.DT.IsExpanded".

Apparently there is no error as I can build, deploy and run.

The First ComboBox control was added using the XAML markup. The second one was dragged and dropped on the DESIGN area.

When the app runs, I can only see the one that was dropped from the Toolbox.[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Apparently there is no error as I can build, deploy and run.

In this case, this should be a design time error.  It seems like you may use the  `Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.4`. Please try to upgrade your `Visual Stuido 2017` to 15.5 or higher to try to fix this issue. Because according to [this similar thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/141386/combobox-issue-with-uwp-16299.html),  this error should be fixed in 15.5.